# Mordecai's Gun Crazy skill + burst fire, what happens?

Tags: borderlands

What happens when Mordecai's Gun Crazy skill is combined with a burst fire repeater?

> #### Gun Crazy
>
> When using Pistols you have 8% chance
> to fire 2 shots with each pull of the
> trigger instead of just 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using any burst fire pistol, Mordecai's gun crazy has a chance to double the amount of rounds in the spread. This applies to both burst fire repeaters and mashers.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying at Gun Crazy lvl 1 Mordecai has an 8% chance to fire off 10 rounds with one trigger pull when using a 5 round burst fire repeater?

Comment: @deft_code Yes. This isn't as good as it sounds though because there are large pauses between bursts. An extremely fast repeater usually performs better. However, this skill is a must if you're using Mashers; x14 burst turns your pistol into a long-range shotgun.

Comment: You imply that Gun Crazy causes you to involuntarily fire a second shot, with a pause in between with burst-fire repeaters. I challenge that this is erroneous if not simply a bias against burst-fire repeaters, contextually moot to the Gun Crazy skill. If you mean that since machine pistols (what you mean by "an extremely fast repeater") may have a chance to proc per shot rather than per burst-fire in the case of burst-fire repeaters, you haven't explained so.

Comment: I mean that machine pistols do have a chance to proc per shot, and burst-fire pistols have a chance to proc *per burst*, meaning each burst counts as a single shot. The damage output is the same with both, but machine pistols have consistency whereas burst-fire pistols have wild spikes because bursts are less frequently fired than a machine pistol can fire single shots.